# How to connect to SQL Server using JDBC Driver 9.2?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm having some trouble connecting my Spring Boot application to SQL Server with the latest version of Microsoft JDBC Driver (9.2). With Java 11, the error I'm getting:

```
2021-07-22 17:39:36.729  WARN 10776 --- [           main] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.AuthenticationJNI   : InitializeSecurityContext failed with -2146893042{WINERR}.
2021-07-22 17:39:36.730  WARN 10776 --- [           main] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.AuthenticationJNI   : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI@576b7c74 Authentication failed code : -2146893042

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:5e003e6a-4721-4bdc-8c61-1bd354794e3b
```

The `application.properties` file (note that the server name, FLÉK, uses unicode formatting):

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://FL\u00C9K:1433;databasename=MyDatabase;integratedSecurity=true
```

And the `pom.xml` includes following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
```

What I've tried so far:

- download the latest Microsoft JDBC Driver version
- place `mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64.dll` inside /windows/system32
- place `mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64.dll` inside JDK's `/bin/` folder
- add installation folder (containing the right Jar file) to `PATH` variable so that the classpath would be set
- set up SQL server to allow TCP/IP connection
- set connection port of server to 1433
- enable mixed mode authentication for the server in SQL Server Management Studio
- restart server a couple of times

If I stop the server, I get an exception saying that the server FLÉK either has no TCP/IP connection allowed, the port is not available or the server is not running, so I'm not sure whether the issue is on the driver's side.

Nothing has worked so far. What step of the configuration am I missing?

Comment: Does the SQL Server's ERRORLOG show any additional information about the login failure? Login failure details are written to the ERRORLOG, and not sent to the client.

Comment: If the problem would have been loading the jdbc_auth DLL, you would have received a different error.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft There is no new ERRORLOG generated when I run the app so I suppose whatever it is, it doesn't get logged on SQL Server's side.

Comment: Can you connect to the database through SSMS, using the same connection string?

Comment: @AndrewS I'm not sure what you mean, as far as I know there is only one way to connect to an engine in Management Studio, no need for connection string.

Comment: @AndrewS okay, apparently trying to connect using connection string keywords doesn't work and I get a `A network-related error or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 11001)` in SSMS despite server and server browser both running, and TCP/IP enabled in Configuration Manager.